# logarithmic find value N.

Tags: logarithms

> $\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log24-\log0.375-6\log3)$ find value N.

I did it below step

> $\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log64-6\log3)$
>   $\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log0.877)$ 
>   I don't know how continue further

the answer from book is 
$N=\frac{2}{3}^3$ 
$N=\frac{8}{27}$

Thanks your help!

Comment: You need to learn the rules for adding, subtracting and multiplying logarithms, before you can hope to do this kind of problem.  The rules you need are $\log x + \log y = \log xy$, $\log x - \log y = \log (x/y)$ and $ x \log y = \log y^x$.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log24-\log0.375-6\log3)$$
$$\log N=\frac{1}{2}(6\log2 -6\log3)$$
$$\log N=(3\log2 -3\log3)$$
$$\log N=(\log8 -\log27)$$

Basically,
$$a \log b = \log (b^a)$$

Comment: Basically $8 = 2^3$ and $27 = 3^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log24-\log0.375-6\log3)$

= $\frac{1}{2}(\log24-(\log0.375+\log3^6))$    since b $\log a = log a^b$

= $\frac{1}{2}(\log24-(\log0.375 *3^6))$

=$\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{24}{0.375 *3^6}$

= $\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{8*3}{(0.5)^3*3 *3^6}$

=$\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{8}{(\frac12)^3 *3^6}$

= $\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{8*8}{3^6}$
=$\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{8}{3^3})^2$

=$\log\frac{8}{3^3}$

There fore,
$N = \frac{8}{27}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log N=\frac{1}{2}(\log24-\log0.375-6\log3)$$

$$\log N= \log \left(\sqrt{\frac{24}{\frac{3}{8}\times 3^6}  }\right)$$

$$ N= \sqrt{\frac{3 \times 8 \times 8}{3 \times 3^6}  } = \frac{8}{27} = \left(\frac23\right)^3  $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that logarith is 1-1 function so you can equate arguments of two logarithms of the same base provided the values are identical. Also try to use suggestion given by Nunoxic.